# Productivity and wages in a task-based model

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, inequality, productivity, technology

In a task-based model like the one developed in Acemoglu&Autor 2011 with two types of worker, can the low type have a higher wage with respect to the high type?

More specifically: if the productivity of the "high type" is greater for **each** task in the economy, can we say that, regardless of the aggregate supply of labor, the equilibrium relationship is $w_h>w_l$?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give a brief outline of the model's setup, or at least give a link to the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that set-up, the wages are related by the following: $w_h\geq w_l$. But it can never happen the low skill earn more. This crucially comes from the fact the high skill have equal or higher productivity than low skill in *any* task.

By contradiction, if it's the case that $w_l>w_h$, then a firm could offer a higher wage to the high skill and substitute the low skill, thus increasing production.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are referring to a situation in which abundand supply of high-skilled workers decrease productivity such that individual $w_h < w_l$
Considering Equation (5) in [Acemoglu & Autor](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.308.299&rep=rep1&type=pdf), $H$ and $L$ capture supply of both groups of workers. If $\frac{H}{L}$ becomes sufficiently high, I don't see why the relation between both wages should not become lower than 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I don't see how a worker who has a productivity higher than the other - in each task - could earn a lower wage. I don't have an intuitive answer to this problem, even though I see your point, and from the equation you mention it seems to be possible.

Comment: Check out the remarks in the paper below that equation. As far as I understand, if `H/L` becomes too high, high-skilled workers will do what low-skilled workers did before and vice versa. This is partly a consequence of the production function with one commodity and no differentiation between tasks.